# What sort of hardware is required to support a network deployment that can support 25,000 transactions per day

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to analyse what sort of hardware is required to support a network deployment as below diagram that can support 25,000 transactions per day.
[image]

Comment: Why the close comments ? Why not provide references? Where else do we seek answers ?

Comment: It is disappointing and disgusting to see the 'few' people close voting even without giving reasons . Seems like 'brutal' over confident moderating. I ask the close voting 'contributors' to point to 'REFERENCE' material answering for the query i have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer when so many free variables are present.

Hardware can be divided into several aspects:

- CPU: Obviously the more the better, and it depends on how these 25k transactions per day are distributed throughout the day.
- Memory: From my experience, peers need more than 2GB of memory, and as for orderers - check the official recommendations for Kafka and Zookeeper in their corresponding sites.
- Storage: 25,0000 Transactions per day means roughly 75MB of data per day, which means about 27GB of data per year. That is if the endorsement policy requires only 1 signature. For 2 signatures its roughly 100MB of data per day, 36GB per year.
- Network bandwidth: The orderers need sufficient bandwidth to support peers that pull blocks from them. To reduce this number, you can configure peers to use gossip and therefore to disseminate blocks among each other, thus reducing the bandwidth load on orderers.